# Why does mat-tree toggle throws error when used to create story file?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have created a tree component using mat-tree in a storybook module, and when I use it inside a component it works just fine. The problem is when I use it to create a story in the storybook.
Same data is used in both cases.

The first error that it throws is:

```
'A valid data sorce must be provided'
```

When clicked on toggle icon, it gives the following error:

```
Error: this._tree.treeControl.toggle is not a function     at MatTreeNodeToggle._toggle
```

Could it be related to some missing dependency?

Here is the tree component:

```
</mat-tree>
  <div class="box">
    <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
      <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.title">
            <mat-icon>
                  {{ treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right' }}
            </mat-icon>
          </button>
          <span fxFlex class="nb-product-title" [innerHTML]="node.title || ''"></span>
        </mat-tree-node>
      </div>
    </mat-tree>
```

The component:

```
    export class TreeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  treeData?: TreeData[];
private _transformer = (node: TreeData, level: number) => {
    return {
      expandable: !!node.children && node.children.length > 0,
      level: level,
      title: node.title,
      type: node.type || '',
      template: node.template || '',
      status: node.status || '',
      assignee: node.assignee || '',
      src: node.src || '',
    };
  };

  treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<TreeFlatNode>(
    node => node.level,
    node => node.expandable
  );

  treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(
    this._transformer,
    node => node.level,
    node => node.expandable,
    node => node.children
  );

  dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);

  ngOnInit() {
    // @ts-ignore
    this.dataSource.data = this.treeData;
  }

  hasChild = (_: number, node: TreeFlatNode) => node.expandable;
}
```

The story where I use this tree component:

```
     imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FlexModule,
        SharedModule,
        MatTreeModule,
        IconModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        ChipModule,
        MatIconModule,
        IconButtonModule,
        IconTextButtonModule,
        PaginationNavigationModule,
        ProfileModule,
        ButtonModule,
        HttpClientModule,
      ],
    }),
  ],
} as Meta;

const TREE_DATA: TreeData[] = [
  {
    title: 'some title text',
    type: 'radio',
    template: 'Live',
    status: 'Reduced',
    assignee: '',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'fj',
        type: 'home',
        template: 'Audio',
        status: 'Draft',
        assignee: 'string',
      },
      {
        title: 'fj',
        type: 'tv',
        template: 'Picture',
        status: 'Ready',
        assignee: 'string',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'string',
    type: 'Web',
    template: 'Live',
    status: 'Draft',
    assignee: 'Tes',
  },
];

const Template: Story<TreeComponent> = (args: TreeComponent) => ({
  component: TreeComponent,
  props: args,
  template: '<app-tree' + ' [treeData]="treeData">' + '</app-tree>',
});

export const Tree = Template.bind({});
Tree.args = {
  treeData: TREE_DATA,
};
```

Comment: Could you solved this problem?. I hace the same issue right now.

Comment: @GerardoGuevara, there is this bug in storybook https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/17004

Comment: one of the workaround is  by disabling the docs addon in main.js, it works @GerardoGuevara

Answer (score 0):

You need to reply to the functions into the component to the storybook page.

```
export class TreeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  treeData?: TreeData[];
_transformer = (node: TreeData, level: number) => {
    return {
      expandable: !!node.children && node.children.length > 0,
      level: level,
      title: node.title,
      type: node.type || '',
      template: node.template || '',
      status: node.status || '',
      assignee: node.assignee || '',
      src: node.src || '',
    };
  };

  treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<TreeFlatNode>(
    node => node.level,
    node => node.expandable
  );

  treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(
    this._transformer,
    node => node.level,
    node => node.expandable,
    node => node.children
  );

  dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);

  ngOnInit() {
    // @ts-ignore
    this.dataSource.data = this.treeData;
  }

  hasChild = (_: number, node: TreeFlatNode) => node.expandable;
}
```

like this into the storybook page js

```
const TREE_DATA: TreeData[] = [
  {
    title: 'some title text',
    type: 'radio',
    template: 'Live',
    status: 'Reduced',
    assignee: '',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'fj',
        type: 'home',
        template: 'Audio',
        status: 'Draft',
        assignee: 'string',
      },
      {
        title: 'fj',
        type: 'tv',
        template: 'Picture',
        status: 'Ready',
        assignee: 'string',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'string',
    type: 'Web',
    template: 'Live',
    status: 'Draft',
    assignee: 'Tes',
  },
];

 const _transformer = (node: TreeData, level: number) => {
        return {
          expandable: !!node.children && node.children.length > 0,
          level: level,
          title: node.title,
          type: node.type || '',
          template: node.template || '',
          status: node.status || '',
          assignee: node.assignee || '',
          src: node.src || '',
        };
      };
    
     const treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<TreeFlatNode>(
        node => node.level,
        node => node.expandable
      );
    
     const treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(
        this._transformer,
        node => node.level,
        node => node.expandable,
        node => node.children
      );
const hasChild = (_: number, node: TreeFlatNode) => node.expandable;

const dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);

export const Tree = Template.bind({});
Tree.args = {
  treeData: TREE_DATA,
_transformer: _transformer,
treeControl: treeControl,
treeFlattener: treeFlattener,
hasChild: hasChild,
dataSource: dataSource
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a bug in storybook:
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/17004

Workaround for now is: by disabling the docs addon in main.js

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I managed to make it work by excluding the attributes from the controls, thus storybook won't take them as control inputs and won't overwrite the attributes with stringified versions from the controls panel.

With the same component as the original post I added in my .stories.ts file :

```
parameters: {
  controls: {
    exclude: ['dataSource', 'transformer', 'treeControl', 'treeFlattener', 'hasChild', 'hasNoContent'],
  }
}
```